# psycopg2 NotSupportedError on "current" when I'm using current_date

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to access a postgresql 8.4 database, and on an update query I get the following exception:

```
  File "/home/alf/cubicweb/cubicweb/server/sources/native.py", line 744, in doexec
    cursor.execute(str(query), args)
NotSupportedError: ERREUR:  la valeur « current » pour la date et heure n'est plus supportée
LINE 1: UPDATE cw_ImportLog SET cw_import_date=E'CURRENT_DATE'
```

the error message is localized but translates to "the value 'current' for date and time is no longer supported".

What bothers me is that the rest of the error message cleary mentions `CURRENT_DATE` is being used, and not `CURRENT`. I can "fix" the exception by using `today` instead of `CURRENT_DATE` in my query but I'd like to understand what's going on in there. Is this a psycopg2 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the string 'CURRENT_DATE' to a date-column. Most likely it uses _ as an accepted separator when parsing the string as a date.

What you want is `CURRENT_DATE` not `'CURRENT_DATE'`.

So try this:

```
UPDATE cw_ImportLog SET cw_import_date = current_date;
```

**Edit**: If you have to feed it a string, use `now` instead, which is valid. See end of [section 9.9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in the docs about it.

Comment: the thing is, current_date is a substituted value, passed in a dictionary, and the driver is supposed to perform the substitution (that's why you see a "E" in the query value)

Comment: Not sure if there is a mapping for a python object to current_date actually. If you feed it as a string, why not use `today` as in your example or `now`? Edit: Of course you can feed it the actual day in python, using datetime.now() or whatever you want.

Comment: the thing is, I'm pretty sure it has worked with now in the past (the code has been there for the past 3 years at least), and I'm not aware of anything changing recently in the installed software / db installation...

Comment: I was getting the same error on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but now worked.